# select entity limit relation depth with manyToMany relation

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

in my app, i have users.
Each user has one Role (Admin, Tester, ...)
each role can have several Permissions (homepage-view, contactpage-view ...)

So, i have a ManyToMany relation

Because i want to get Roles from permissions and permissions from roles, i have a bidirectionnal relation.

What i want is just to select one permission with its roles

My problem : when i get a permission, it gets each role with its permissions with its roles ...

Result begin example :

```
{
  "id": 4,
  "nom": "Accès au backoffice",
  "slug": "page-backoffice",
  "role": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "libelle": "Administrateur",
      "permission": [
        {
          "id": 3,
          "nom": "Visualisation du stock global",
          "slug": "page-visu-stock-global",
          "role": [
            {
              "id": 2,
              "libelle": "Responsable d'exploitation",
              "permission": [
                {
                  .......
```

What i want is :

```
{
  "id": 4,
  "nom": "Accès au backoffice",
  "slug": "page-backoffice",
  "role": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "libelle": "Administrateur",
      "slug": "administrateur"
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "libelle": "Responsable d'exploitation",
      "slug": "responsable-exploitation"
    },
    ....
```

How can i do it ?

my orm file relation details :
Permissions.orm.yml :

```
manyToMany:
    role:
        targetEntity: Role
        cascade: {  }
        fetch: LAZY
        mappedBy: permission
        inversedBy: null
        joinTable: null
        orderBy: null
```

role.orm.yml :

```
 manyToMany:
    permission:
        targetEntity: Permissions
        cascade: {  }
        fetch: LAZY
        mappedBy: null
        inversedBy: role
        joinTable:
            name: role_permission
            joinColumns:
                -
                    name: role_id
                    referencedColumnName: id
            inverseJoinColumns:
                -
                    name: permission_id
                    referencedColumnName: id
        orderBy: null
```

Thanks for your help

Comment: You should look at the [serialization groups](https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/serializer.html#component-serializer-attributes-groups) and [how to enable them](https://symfony.com/doc/current/serializer.html#using-serialization-groups-annotations). Hope it may help you

Comment: using serialisation won't prevent doctrine to fetch data doing the loop permission > role > permission > role ... Am i wrong ?

Comment: you are in lazy fetch so fetch happend only when data are required. Fact is you presented your object as a json, i assumed it was serialized for an api

Comment: I use symfony as my Rest API for a SPA application. So in showed the JSON i received. So if i use a serializer, it will prevent doctrine to do the loop and i will improve performances ?? I this the good way to do it or do i have to use DQL to do a specific query selecting exactly the fileds i need ? Thanks

Comment: Then serializer and serialization group should be enough

Comment: @OlivierC: Could you please elaborate your comments into a real answer? Your chance to win some unicorn points, and it would prevent others from stumbling over an “unanswered”, yet resolved question.

Comment: @lxg just rewrote my comments into an answer to help in the future

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mostly you don't want to expose all your entity at a time into your api and more particularly when exposing related entities into others.

Serialization groups allow you to choose which attributes you want to expose in your api. By this way you can avoid to roll into the deep when exposing related entities (like a role exposing its permissions exposing their roles exposing their permissions to the infinite and beyond).

Symfony have some piece of documentation about [what are serialization groups](https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/serializer.html#attributes-groups) and [how to enable and use serialization groups](https://symfony.com/doc/current/serializer.html#using-serialization-groups-annotations).

Answer (score -1):

Here is an example of how to do it:

```
use JMS\Serializer\Annotation\MaxDepth;

class User
{
    private $username;

    /** @MaxDepth(1) */
    private $friends;

    /** @MaxDepth(2) */
    private $posts;
}

class Post
{
    private $title;

    private $author;
}
```

And for controller:

```
use JMS\Serializer\SerializationContext;

$serializer->serialize($data, 'json', SerializationContext::create()->enableMaxDepthChecks());
```

Note there are around 20 annotation keywords to "filter" data during serialisation.

Example source:

http://jmsyst.com/libs/serializer/master/cookbook/exclusion_strategies#limiting-serialization-depth-of-some-properties